# Can some one be a bygone?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I said 'you are a bygone' to somebody older then me in reference to him not understanding how attending a coding boot camp can train people to become full stack engineers and get a career at a legitimate technology company. Did I use the word right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say 'no', "You are from a bygone era." would be fine, but it's not a word I would use applied to people. Well, not living people.